# lodash fp and refactoring some existing code

Tags: javascript, refactoring, lodash

I'm learning functional programming and I'm trying to refactor a piece of old code using lodash FP.

Here's the code I have:

```
_.filter(x => isIdInArray(x)(xs))(otherXs)
```

It's too complicated to read and makes me feel a bit weird (smell ?)

My problem is that x value, that is the first argument of isIdInArray is declared this way:

```
const getId = _.get('id');
const isIdInArray = _.compose(_.includes, getId);
```

I can't use my lodash filter function this way:

```
_.filter(isIdInArray(xs))(otherXs)
```

I don't even know if it's feasible, but I'm pretty sure I can do something  clearer or more readable.

Do you have some ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're writing production code, I recommend using a higher-level function. In your particular case I'd say you need `_.intersectionBy`:

```
const keepIfIdInArray = _.intersectionBy('id'); // 'id' can be replaced by your getId
const keepIfIdInOtherXs = keepIfIdInArray(otherXs);
keepIfIdInOtherXs(xs);
```

If you're doing this as an exercice, then I'd say you may need to decompose a little more. Notice that in lodash/fp, `_.includes` is curried so you should be able to write the following:

```
const getId = _.get('id');
const isIdInArray = arr => _.compose(_.includes(arr), getId);
const isIdInOtherXs = isIdInArray(otherXs);
_.filter(isIdInOtherXs)(xs);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try not to stuff all the fancy features that lodash gives you into a single line there.
Having a complex mechanism in one line may seem nice, but if you can't read it anymore its not very helpful at all.

For managing collections i usually use approaches like this:

```
var collection = [{id: 'a', someField: 1}, {id:'b', someField: 2}];
var theIdsYoureLookingFor = ['a'];

var filtered = collection
                .filter(anyObject => _.includes(theIdsYoureLookingFor, anyObject.id))
                .map(anyObject => anyObject.someField);

alert(filtered); // alerts 1
```

Which parses a collection of objects, filters for those who have an id that you consider valid and then maps those objects to a certain field.

Also don't ever use variable names like: x, xs